# Unable to generate FMX in oracle apps r12.1.3

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

I am new to the oracle apps form development.
i am unable to generate .FMX file using below command in putty.

```
frmcmp_batch.sh module=/u01/install/APPS/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US/EMP.fmb 
userid=apps/apps 
    output_file=/u01/install/APPS/apps/apps_st/appl/po/12.0.0/forms/US/EMP.fmx module_type=form
```

Please help me on the same.

Thanks&Regards,
Vivek

Comment: where is batch=yes you have to add that also

Answer (score 0):

you may call a script from the command line

```
$ appCompile.sh EMP.fmb
```

where appCompile.sh maybe like below one

```
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/install/APPS/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US; export ORACLE_HOME
export NLS_LANG=american_america.we8iso8859p9 #for Turkish
NLS_DATE_FORMAT=DD/MM/YYYY; export NLS_DATE_FORMAT
FORMS_PATH=/data/aski_kodlar/standard; export FORMS_PATH
alias oh='cd $ORACLE_HOME'
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/install/APPS/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US/lib:/u01/install/APPS/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US/jdk/jre/lib/sparcv9:
/u01/install/APPS/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US/jdk/jre/lib/sparcv9/server:/u01/install/APPS/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US/jdk/jre/lib/sparcv9/native_threads
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export ORACLE_TERM=vt220
export TERM=xterm
type=$2

if test "$type" = ""
then
 type=form
fi

echo Compiling Form $1 ....
filename=`echo $1|cut -f1 -d.`
/u01/install/APPS/apps/apps_st/appl/scripts/frmcmp_batch.sh userid=apps/apps@db_name Module_Type=$type  compile_all=yes window_state=minimize batch=yes Module=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Before compile you must SET the environment variables in linux, it depends on which kind of environment you are logged in, if it is Oracle On-Demand or Custom.

For custom:
Search a file extension .env
Usually located in /u01/oracle/EBS/app, run that file to SET environment variables.

For Oracle On-Demand:
In Linux SSH, run comand below where XXXX is the database
pbrun impdba -u apXXXX

Afer that you must run your compleation script.

1. Put your promp in

cd $AU_TOP/forms/US
export PATH=$PATH:$AU_TOP/resource:$AU_TOP/forms/US

2. Run compilation script by replacing APPS_PASSWORD, XXCUST_TOP, XX_FORM_FILE.

frmcmp_batch module=$XXHMS_TOP/forms/US/XX_FORM_FILE.fmb userid=apps/APPS_PASSWORD output_file=$XXCUST_TOP/forms/US/XX_FORM_FILE.fmx compile_all=special batch=yes

It will create a LOG file with .err extension.

Answer (score 0):

this would help :

```
frmcmp_batch module=/disk5/PROD/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US/EMP.fmb userid=apps/apps output_file=/disk5/PROD/apps/apps_st/appl/ont/12.0.0/forms/US/EMP.fmx module_type=form batch=yes
```